# Remove more than one field from front end submission form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

In the below example, I have removed a trim field from add vehicle form. There are more form items I wish to remove , how can I add more than one item to remove.
Here is the form I want to edit
https://www.d-autoville.com/add-car

```
add_filter('cdfs_car_form_fields_items', 'cdfs_car_form_fields_items_custom', 10, 1);
function cdfs_car_form_fields_items_custom($form_fields) {
   for ($i=0; $i<count($form_fields); $i++) {
      if ($form_fields[$i]['name'] == 'trim') {
         unset($form_fields[$i]);
         break;
      }
   }
   return $form_fields;
}
```

Comment: named fields or just from the bottom?

Comment: Name fields, the text boxes as well as the text area